# Display an image in each button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

First, I'm a newbie in XAML and C#, I try to learn.

In my main window I have two button. In each button i want to display an image.
In the first button when I click on it, the image change.
In the second button when I click on it, it's close the application.

My problem is when I lauch the application,the image appear only in the first button.
And I don't understand why.
I can't see the image in the second button...

Could you tell me what I've done wrong, please?

My .XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ObjFlauraud.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObjFlauraud"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="800"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        Top="0"   
>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="KeyAffiche" Source="down-arrow.png" />
        <Image x:Key="KeyCache" Source="up-arrow.png" />
        <Image x:Key="KeyClose" Source="fermer.png" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <GroupBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,-7,-7">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="BtnAffiche" Width="16" Height="16" Click="BtnAffiche_Click">
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="KeyCache"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="BtnFermer" Width="16" Height="16" Click="BtnFermer_Click" Content="{DynamicResource KeyClose}">
                    
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

My .cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ObjFlauraud
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Left = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / 2) - (this.Width / 2);
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Topmost = true;
        }

        private void BtnAffiche_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BtnAffiche.Content == FindResource("KeyCache"))
            {
                BtnAffiche.Content = FindResource("KeyAffiche");
                this.Top = this.Top - this.Height + BtnAffiche.Height + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                BtnAffiche.Content = FindResource("KeyCache");
                this.Top = 0;
            }
        }

        private void BtnFermer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MathewHD These are different notations for the same thing, both are correct. @Franck Do you get any errors in the output window? Try to specify the `KeyClose` resource in the first button. If it does not work, it is more likely that there is a typo in the file name or the file does not exist.

Comment: @thatguy I've no error in the output windows. I tried to change the image by another and it's work. i think my first image was bugged... Thank you for the help.